# How to Delete Export Folder?

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, export

I am trying to delete one invalid folder from magento default export functionality. But its throwing on error page.

I have attached images, looks like magento default issue. If anyone faced this issue and have any solution then please help me with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need to check.

Comment: Ok, please check, if you want generate this issue manually, Then Create var/export inside blank "email" folder. Then check above issue.